# I am trying to solve this database problems

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to solve the problems below I have included what I have got already. the questions are below.

This is what I have done.

````
CREATE TABLE casino (
  casino_id int, -- a primary key
);

CREATE TABLE games (
  id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (casino_id) REFERENCES casinos (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE countries (
  id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (games_id) REFERENCES games (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Question 2:

SELECT  *
FROM    players   
        LEFT JOIN games 
            ON players.id = games.id AND
                games.type LIKE ‘%SLOT%'
ORDER   BY players.id


SELECT *
FROM players LEFT OUTER JOIN players ON players.id = games.id 
WHERE games.type LIKE '%SLOT%'
ORDER BY players.id ```
````

Comment: you need for both relationships a table that connects countries and games and games and casino for the game table needs a type column, which you described in your select

Comment: @nbk I dont understand do I need a player table as well

Comment: you need also a player table, but you consteallation don't allows one game to be played in different casinos , alsohow do you want to link game a to austrlaia, egland, brasil game 2 australia, brasil and urguay

Comment: @nbk okay thank you which table will the player table have a one to many relationship with?

Comment: one with countries, that decides which games he is allowed to play for example slots, but there is the problem with the favourite type, so you must also have a link to a type table, which also is referenced by game,

Comment: @nbk Okay could you give help me with the implementation of the sql statement. I am still not getting the full picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of making it

Type is here only char, usually type should be a table, so that a games could be many types, but that would make the query even bigger

> ```
> CREATE TABLE countries (
>   id int,
>   Country_name CHAR(20),
>   PRIMARY KEY (id)
> );
> CREATE TABLE players (
>   id int,
>   ref_country_id INT,
>   type CHAR(50),
>   PRIMARY KEY (id),
>   FOREIGN KEY (ref_country_id) REFERENCES countries (id) 
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE games (
>   id int,
>   name char(50),
>   type CHAR(50),
>   PRIMARY KEY (id)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE rel_country_games (
>   ref_country_id int,
>   ref_games_id INT,
>   FOREIGN KEY (ref_country_id) REFERENCES countries (id),
>   FOREIGN KEY (ref_games_id) REFERENCES games (id)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE casino (
>   casino_id int,
>   casino_name char(100),
>   PRIMARY KEY (casino_id)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE rel_country_games (
>   ref_casino_id int,
>   ref_games_id INT,
>   FOREIGN KEY (ref_casino_id) REFERENCES casino (casino_id),
>   FOREIGN KEY (ref_games_id) REFERENCES games (id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO countries VALUES(1,'Brasil'),(2,'Uruguay'),(3,'MExico')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO players VALUES(1,1,NULL),(2,1,'SLOT'),(3,2,'SLOT'),(4,3,'POKER')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO games VALUES(1,'slotgame1','SLOT'),(2,'slotgame2','SLOT'),(3,'poker','POKER');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO rel_country_games VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,3)
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT DISTINCT p.id,c.Country_name,p.type,g.type
>     FROM players p INNER JOIN countries  c ON c.id = p.ref_country_id 
>     INNER JOIN rel_country_games rcg ON c.id = rcg.ref_country_id
>     INNER JOIN games g ON rcg.ref_games_id = g.id AND g.type = p.type
>     WHERE p.type = 'SLOT'
>     ORDER BY p.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | Country_name | type | type
> -: | :----------- | :--- | :---
>  2 | Brasil       | SLOT | SLOT
>  3 | Uruguay      | SLOT | SLOT
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd52d70a7748206ad1a6d6c414c86b9b)*

If you have difficulties to play around with this in your mind, simply make a simple example and test your ideas.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate. Advise noted.

Comment: Okay I will. I might delete it